# Concrete variational equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having a really hard time with this problem. I would really appreciate some help. I am trying to review for a class and I was looking at old hw problems I could never figure out.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting

$\mathbf x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}, \tag 1$

then

$f(\mathbf x) = \begin{pmatrix}  -x_1 \\ -x_2 + x_1^2 \\ x_3 + x_1^2  \end{pmatrix}; \tag 2$

we wish to solve

$\dot{\mathbf x} = f(\mathbf x), \; \mathbf x(0) = \mathbf y =  \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{pmatrix}, \tag 3$

which, due to the particular form of $f(\mathbf x)$, is relatively straightforward; we note that (2)-(3) indicate that

$\dot x_1 = -x_1, \; x_1(0) = y_1, \tag 4$

a simple equation for $x_1(t)$ alone, the solution of which is well-known to be

$x_1(t) = y_1 e^{-t}; \tag 5$

from (3) and (5) we have

$\dot x_2(t) = -x_2 + x_1^2 = -x_2 + y_1^2e^{-2t}, \; x_2(0) = y_2; \tag 6$

(6) is an inhomogeneous linear equation, easily solved:

$x_2(t) = \displaystyle e^{-t} ( y_2 + y_1^2 \int_0^t e^s e^{-2s} ds) = y_2e^{-t} + y_1^2 e^{-t} \int_0^t e^s e^{-2s}ds$
$= y_2e^{-t} + y_1^2 e^{-t} \int_0^t e^{-s}ds = y_2e^{-t} +y_1^2 e^{-t}(1 - e^{-t}) = y_2e^{-t} + y_1^2 e^{-t} - y_1^2 e^{-2t}; \tag 7$

the reader may easily check (7) if it is so desired; (7) shows a partial outworking of the standard and well-known formula

$x(t) = \displaystyle \exp(-\int_0^t a(s) \; ds)(x(0) + \int_0^t \exp(\int_0^s a(u) du) b(s) ds) \tag 8$

for the solution of the first order, linear, time-dependent ordinary differential equation

$\dot x(t) + a(t)x(t) = b(t) \tag 9$

as applied to (6).  Again from (3) and (5) we see that

$\dot x_3 = x_3 + y_1^2 e^{-2t}, \; x_3(0) = y_3, \tag{10}$

with solution

$x_3(t) = \displaystyle e^t (y_3 + y_1^2 \int_0^t e^{-s} e^{-2s}ds) = e^t (y_3 + y_1^2 \int_0^t e^{-3s}ds)$
$= e^t(y_3 + \dfrac{y_1^2}{3}(1 - e^{-3t})); \tag{11}$

$x_3(t) = y_3 e^t + \dfrac{y_1^2}{3} e^t - \dfrac{y_1^2} e^{-2t}; \tag{12}$

Assembling (5), (7), and (12) we find

$\varphi(t, y) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \\ x_3(t) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}  y_1 e^{-t} \\ y_2e^{-t} + y_1^2 e^{-t} - y_1^2 e^{-2t} \\  y_3 e^t + \dfrac{y_1^2}{3} e^t - \dfrac{y_1^2}{3} e^{-2t} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}  y_1 e^{-t} \\ y_2e^{-t} + y_1^2 ( e^{-t} -  e^{-2t}) \\  y_3 e^t + \dfrac{y_1^2}{3}( e^t -  e^{-2t}) \end{pmatrix},\tag{13}$

we have thus presented the solution $\varphi(t, y)$ of the system (2).

Next, we have

$\Phi(t, y) = D_2 \varphi(t, y) = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial \varphi_i (t, y)}{\partial y_j} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} e^{-t} & 0 & 0 \\ 2 y_1 ( e^{-t} -  e^{-2t}) & e^{-t} & 0 \\  \dfrac{2y_1}{3}( e^t -  e^{-2t}) & 0 & e^t \end{bmatrix}; \tag{14}$

hence,

$\dfrac{d \Phi(t, y)}{dt} =  \begin{bmatrix} -e^{-t} & 0 & 0 \\ 2 y_1 ( 2e^{-2t} -  e^{-t}) & -e^{-t} & 0 \\  \dfrac{2y_1}{3}( e^t +  2e^{-2t}) & 0 & e^t \end{bmatrix}; \tag{15}$

also,

$Df(\mathbf x) = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial f_i(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_j} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 2x_1 & -1 & 0 \\ 2x_1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \tag{16}$

so it follows that

$Df(\varphi(t, y)) = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 2y_1 e^{-t} & -1 & 0 \\ 2y_1 e^{-t} & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \tag{17}$

and we have

$Df(\varphi(t, y)) \Phi(t, y) = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 2y_1 e^{-t} & -1 & 0 \\ 2y_1 e^{-t} & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} e^{-t} & 0 & 0 \\ 2 y_1 ( e^{-t} -  e^{-2t}) & e^{-t} & 0 \\  \dfrac{2y_1}{3}( e^t -  e^{-2t}) & 0 & e^t \end{bmatrix}$
$= \begin{bmatrix} -e^{-t} & 0 & 0 \\ 2 y_1 ( 2e^{-2t} -  e^{-t}) & e^{-t} & 0 \\  \dfrac{2y_1}{3}( e^t +  2e^{-2t}) & 0 & e^t \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{d \Phi(t, y)}{dt}, \tag{19}$

as per request.

In closing, I would like to point out that this system is particularly easy to solve by virtue of the fact that the equation for $x_1$, $\dot x_1 = - x_1$, is a simple linear equation which is decoupled from $x_2$ and $x_3$, so even though $x_1$ appears non-linearly in $\dot x_2$, $\dot x_3$, it occurs as a known inhomogeneous term of the then *linear* systems $\dot x_2 = -x_2 + x_1^2 = -x_2 + y_1^2 e^{-2t}$, $\dot x_3 = x_3 + x_1^2 = x_3 + y_1^2 e^{-2t}$.  This decoupling, and the general structure of the system (2), is reflected in (16), which reflects these simplifications  of the vector field $f$ described by (2) in the $x_1, x_2, x_3$ coordinate system.  I suspect that an investigation into the structure of $Df:T_x M \to T_xM$ in a more 
abstract, coordinate-free formalism might lead to the discovery of "good" coordinate systems in which the differential equation (3) becomes as simple as possible; but since I have not results on this concept which I'm ready to share at the moment, I'll take my leave of typing now.

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help out!